# Use node crypto in angular 9

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular9, cryptojs

My project was in Angular 6 and it had following lines of code

```
const crypto = require('crypto-js');
const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
const decrypt = new Buffer(data.result.encr, 'base64');
const privatekey = Buffer.from(data.result.pk, 'base64');
this.decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(privatekey, decrypt).toString('utf-8');
return this.decrypted;
```

Which was working fine.

Now I migrated my code to Angular 9. And I find out that `crypto` has no longer support from NPM

https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto

It says that I have to use inbuild library of crypto. But I have no idea how to use it.

I thought `crypto-js` would help me. But it didn't.

If someone knows how to use `crypto` in Angular 9 or how to convert upper lines for `crypto-js` then it would be great.

Note: Encryption is happening on server side using crypto only as they have nodejs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your node  and npm version ?

Comment: @LogicBlower node version12.14.1 & npm version 6.13.4

Comment: The nodejs `crypto.privateDecrypt ` uses RSA and `crypto-js` has no support for RSA. You might need to have a look at npm libraries like `js-crypto-rsa` or `node-rsa`

Comment: @IvayloIvanov Thanks for your input will check and revert back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 3-4 days I am finally able to resolve this.

1. I installed [crypto-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-browserify).
2. Delete node_modules folder and then again installed all dependencies by using `npm-install`

`crypto-browserify` provides same features as `crypto`

Comment: Tried multiple times but this doesn't work for Angular 11. After Angular 6 process, browser and main were removed. Even after adding a script tag, the pdkf2 ends up importing process.version.split which doesn't exits. You can try continuing down this rabbit hole but it comes down with the package trying to operate as server mode. 

in pbkdf2/lib/default-ecoding.js thinks its running in server mode: 
{code}var defaultEncoding
/* istanbul ignore next */
if (process.browser) {
...
} else if (process.version) {
  var pVersionMajor = parseInt(process.version.split('.')[0].slice(1), 10)

Comment: so @yfeleke what solution did you come up with when working with 11?  I am facing the same issue

Comment: ended up using crypto js: 

import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

and then in package.json

  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }

Answer (score 1):

I recently acheived this in my MEAN Stack app. After installing crypto-js with following command:

```
npm i crypto-js --save
```

Following service in **Angular-9** which can be used through out the project for encryption and decryption.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CryptoJsService {

  constructor() { }

  get jsonFormatter() {
    return {
      stringify: (cipherParams: any) => {
        const jsonObj = { ct: cipherParams.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64), iv: null, s: null };
        if (cipherParams.iv) {
          jsonObj.iv = cipherParams.iv.toString();
        }
        if (cipherParams.salt) {
          jsonObj.s = cipherParams.salt.toString();
        }
        return JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
      },
      parse: (jsonStr) => {
        const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        // extract ciphertext from json object, and create cipher params object
        const cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
          ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(jsonObj.ct)
        });
        if (jsonObj.iv) {
          cipherParams.iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(jsonObj.iv);
        }
        if (jsonObj.s) {
          cipherParams.salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(jsonObj.s);
        }
        return cipherParams;
      }
    };
  }
  /* Method for Encryption */
  encrypt(value: any) {
    const key =  environment.crypto_js_key; // SECRET KEY FOR ENCRYPTION 
    value = value instanceof String ? value : JSON.stringify(value);
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value,key, 
      { format: this.jsonFormatter, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC }).toString();
    return encrypted;
  }

  /* Method for Decryption */
  decrypt(value: any): any {
    const key = environment.crypto_js_key; //SECRET KEY FOR ENCRYPTION
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, key, {format: this.jsonFormatter }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return JSON.parse(decrypted);
  }
}
```

In **Nodejs**, following utility could be used through out the app:

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var config = require('../config/environment');

module.exports.encrypt = function(value){
  var JsonFormatter = {
    stringify: function(cipherParams){
      var jsonObj = { ct: cipherParams.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) };
      if (cipherParams.iv) {
        jsonObj.iv = cipherParams.iv.toString();
      }
      if (cipherParams.salt) {
        jsonObj.s = cipherParams.salt.toString();
      }
      return JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    },
    parse: function(jsonStr) {
      var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
      // extract ciphertext from json object, and create cipher params object
      var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(jsonObj.ct)
      });
      if (jsonObj.iv) {
        cipherParams.iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(jsonObj.iv);
      }
      if (jsonObj.s) {
        cipherParams.salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(jsonObj.s);
      }
      return cipherParams;
    }
  }
  value = value instanceof String ? value: JSON.stringify(value);
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, config.crypto_js_key, {
    format: JsonFormatter, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
  }).toString();
  return encrypted;
}

module.exports.decrypt = function(value) {
  return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(value, config.crypto_js_key, {format: JsonFormatter }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Comment: For Angular 11, this worked but needed this to be added below devDependencies: 
     ```  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }    ```
   Otherwise you will get the error: Warning: ./node_modules/crypto-js/core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/Innov8/x/i8/git/allspark/spark-fe/node_modules/crypto-js'

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the desired hash, the best option for me was [ts-md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-md5) lib.

```
import {Md5} from 'ts-md5/dist/md5';
...
Md5.hashStr('blah blah blah'); // hex:string
Md5.hashStr('blah blah blah', true); // raw:Int32Array(4)
Md5.hashAsciiStr('blah blah blah'); // hex:string
Md5.hashAsciiStr('blah blah blah', true); // raw:Int32Array(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Angular 16 & used crypto inside a method and it worked. I didn't used any packages.

My requirement was to get some random numbers.

```
private getRandomNumbers(){
const array = new Uint32Array(10);
crypto.getRandomValues(array);

for (const num of array) {
  console.log(num);
}
}
```